# Jest not outputting describe names nor test names when more than one test file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

## TLDR

When running [Jest](https://jestjs.io) (23.5.0) with only one file, it outputs 'describe names' and 'test names'. I want Jest to output 'describe names' and 'test names' when running with multiple test files, but it seems to be automatically suppressing.

## TMI

Example:

```
 PASS  src/components/UsersTable.test.jsx
  UsersTable
    ✓ is a table (4ms)
    ✓ has columns 'first', 'last', 'email' (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.768s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
```

When running with two, it suppresses. Example:

```
 PASS  src/components/UsersTableRow.test.jsx
 PASS  src/components/UsersTable.test.jsx

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.254s
Ran all test suites.
```

Partial code sample:

```
describe('UsersTable', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
        <UsersTable />
    );
    const usersTable = component.toJSON();

    test('is a table', () => {
        expect(usersTable.type).toBe('table');
    });
```

Removing 'test' from the name of either file such that only one of the two tests runs at a time, results in successful desired output of name details for either file.  TLDR: Both files work alone.

Answer (score 13):

## TLDR

Run jest with [`--verbose`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#verbose).

Change package.json test script to `jest --verbose`.

## TMI

I tried `npm run test --verbose` which affected the output but didn't include the information I was hoping for.  I mistakenly thought that `--verbose` wasn't the fix.  But in `npm run test --verbose`, I'm mistakenly applying the verbose flag to the npm process, not to jest.

Apparently `jest` is the same as `jest --verbose` if only a single test file exists, but not for two or more.  For two or more, must explicitly include `--verbose`.

Comment: Could also run as "npm run test -- --verbose" so that it passes the arguments to jest.

Answer (score 2):

You can run multiple tests with the `--verbose` flag (as mentioned by Geoffrey Hale in his answer).

You can tell the command line to pass the flag to jest (instead of npm) with `--`:

```
npm run test -- --verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add or set the following property in your **jest** configuration file (**jest.config.ts** or **jest.config.json**) to show the list of your test names and their status.

```
// Indicates whether each individual test should be reported during the run
verbose: true
```

You can read more here:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#verbose-boolean